# Multiple Notifications not showing in android

Tags: android, notifications

In my android app I'm willing to show multiple notifications on a particular day,for this I'm using Alarm Manager and Broadcast Receiver problem is when I used alarm it worked fine but when I add notification builder to show the notification its not working

Here is my mainActivity

```
  public static final String ACTION_ONE = "Hello, Test Message 1";
public static final String ACTION_TWO = "Hello, Test Message 2";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    AlarmManager alarmManager1 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());

    Intent myIntent1 = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadCustReciver.class);
    myIntent1.setAction(ACTION_ONE);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent1 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1253, myIntent1,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Set the time for first alarm here
    cal.set(2015, 10, 20, 15, 55);
    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent1);

    Intent myIntent2 = new Intent(this, AlarmBroadCustReciver.class);
    myIntent2.setAction(ACTION_TWO);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1263, myIntent2,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    // Set the time for second alarm here
    cal.set(2015, 10, 20, 15, 56);
    alarmManager1.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent2);
    // In this way set time for all the rest of the alarms
```

Here is BroadCastReceiver

```
public class AlarmBroadCustReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static final String ACTION_ONE = "Hello, welcome to the Server1";
public static final String ACTION_TWO = "Hello, welcome to the Server2";

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context);
    builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher));
    builder.setContentTitle(context.getString(R.string.app_name));
    if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase(ACTION_ONE)) {
        builder.setContentText("Alarm one");
    } else {
        builder.setContentText("Alarm two");
    }
    Notification notification = builder.build();
    int notificationID = 0;
    notificationManager.notify(notificationID, notification);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass different notification id for each Notification . If you pass same id (i.e., 0 in your case), the existed notification will be updated with the new data.
change the notification id: eg have a variable and increment it. notificationid++

Comment: my issue is even first notification is also not shown.can I have some sample

Comment: check this sample http://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/alarms.html and implement the above logic.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, I was creating multiple notifications with different IDs, however, when I clicked on one, only the first one opened the specific scree, all the sequential notifications were ignore (clicking on them didn't do anything, they were just dismissed). Then I tried to do this:

```
intent.setAction(context.getPackageName() + "." + notificationId);
```

Which means that each unique notification also carries its own unique Intent and in this case the Intents weren't ignored and each of them opened the needed screen. I must note that my Intents were the same (e.g. NoteDetails.class), so I guess I had to separate them somehow...i'm glad it worked anyways.

Answer (score 0):

[Box's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45011660/1617737) was a nudge in the right direction for me.

I just had to change the requestCode in the PendingIntent I was passing to the AlarmManager, so it wasn't the same value.

Old code:

```
PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

New code:

```
PendingIntent pI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, notificationId, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

Comment: I have used different requestCodes, but had flags set at 0. Setting it to `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` solved the problem.