# Notifications not showing in android

Tags: java, android, notifications

I have multiple Notification but, the others are not showing up if the time is up, any Idea how can I fix this every notification have unique data tried this one but not working [Multiple Notifications not showing in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33825664/multiple-notifications-not-showing-in-android)

```
 //Schedule alarm notification
private void scheduleNotification(Notification notification, long delay) {
    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getContext(), MyNotificationPublisher.class);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyNotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION_ID, 1);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyNotificationPublisher.NOTIFICATION, notification);
    notificationIntent.putExtra(MyNotificationPublisher.NOTIF_CONTENT, title);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getContext(), 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    assert alarmManager != null;
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, delay, pendingIntent);
    Log.d(TAG, "scheduleNotification: Notification set successfully!");
}

//Build notification
private Notification getNotification(String content) {
    //on notification click open MainActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), SchedulerFragment.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getContext(), 0, intent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getContext(), default_notification_channel_id);
    builder.setContentTitle("ToDo Reminder");
    builder.setContentText(content);
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
    builder.setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND);
    builder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
    builder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
    return builder.build();
}
```

O
NotificationPublisher

```
 public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH;
        NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(SchedulerFragment.NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_NAME", importance);
        assert notificationManager != null;
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
    }
    int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
    String con = intent.getStringExtra(NOTIF_CONTENT);
    assert notificationManager != null;
    notificationManager.notify(id, notification);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the following code，This method is used to generate notification. If different notifications have different `channelId`, multiple notification can be generated at the same time.

```
    private void initNotification(Context context,String channelId,String channelName,String title,String content){
        Intent activityIntent = new Intent(context,MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,0,activityIntent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                channelName, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
        NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context,channelId)
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setContentText(content)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentIntent(pi)
                .build();
        manager.notify(Integer.parseInt(channelId),notification);
    }
```

Ensure that the value of `String channelID` is different to generate a multiple notification.

[image]

[image]

Comment: User will add the Reminder(notification) possible to add random channel id, and the NotificationManager is in BroadcastReceiver

Comment: The notification of each channel can be displayed at the same time only when the channel IDs are different.